# PHP Extract Not Working on Array

Tags: php, oop, extract

I am trying to get my $viewData into local variables.  Here is my function:

```
function view($layout, $view, $var)
{

    extract($var);
    include($layout);

}
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
$viewData = array($hasImages->arr, $latest->arr, $mostViewed->arr, $all->arr, $this->error);

$this->view('/view/shared/layout.php', '/view/home.php', $viewData);
```

The extract method works fine on the $this->error string, but not on any of the arrays such as $hasImages->arr.  It doesn't seem to create the variable in the local context.

How can I get my arrays into my function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) expects an associative array, so it has keys from which to derive variable names in the scope it's called.

```
// Pass in an associative array
$viewData = array(
  'hasImages' => $hasImages->arr,
  'latest' => $latest->arr,
  'mostViewed' => $mostViewed->arr,
  'all' => $all->arr, 
  'error' => $this->error
);

// After extract(), will produce
$hasImages
$latest
$mostViewed
$all
$error
```

However, I would question the utility of using `extract()` at all. Instead, it may be more readable to use the associative array as above, and access it via keys like `$var['mostViewed']['something']` inside your method.

Answer (score 2):

`$viewData` needs to be an associative array. The keys of the array will be names of the variables once they have been "extracted".